# Finding the mode of propagation of a progressive wave and the velocity of that mode

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, python, wave, array-signal-processing

Injecting a sinusoid say, $Z = A \sin(k_x  X + k_y Y - \omega  t)$, $K = 2 \pi f/c$,
for example, assume $f = 10$ Hz or $50$ Hz, and $c = 50$ m/s, now if I draw the 2D K-space plot with the following script

```
n=40
f = 50  # Temporal frequency in Hz
c = 50  # wave speed 50  m/s
k = 2.0 * np.pi * f / c  # wavenumber
kx = np.linspace(-k, k, n * 10)  # space vector
ky = np.linspace(-k, k, n * 10)  # space vector
X, Y = np.meshgrid(kx,ky) 
t= np.arange(0, n, 1)

#2D sine wave 
d2_sig = np.sin(-(kx*X+ky*Y)+2.0 * np.pi *f*2) 


plt.figure()
c = plt.imshow(d2_sig, cmap='seismic', vmin=d2_sig.min(), vmax=d2_sig.max(),
                   extent=[kx.min(), kx.max(), ky.min(), ky.max()],
                   interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')
plt.colorbar(c)
plt.xlabel("Wavenumber, $K_x$ [rad/m]", fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel("Wavenumber,$K_y$ [rad/m]", fontsize=18)
plt.title(f'Progressive wave', weight="bold")
```

The plot I get:[image: Fig. 01: 2-D sine wave in K-space]

[image: Fig.02: 1-D sinusoid in K-space]

I'm worried to find the modes of propagation of the wave vector and also the speed of the wave.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdzDT.png): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYT3x.png![Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYT3x.png!%5BFigure) 03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4bDn.png)

How do I interpret the image in figure 03 representing spatial spectrum of a Wave, where the spatial spectrum is expressed by the equation
[image: Equation for spatial spectrum]

Here, $C(r_i,r_j,\omega)$ represents the cross-spectral density between every pair of sensors. $k=2\pi f/c$ is the wavenumber   $r_i, r_j$ be the position of sensors.

N.B. I've pointed out what was going wrong on the above script to generate a 2D spatial plane wave and the answer has provided in the following.

However, I've experienced another problem to inject a planar Sine wave to spatially positioned sensors, the sensor position has known to me and I provide the sensor position as follows:

```
x = [2.1, 2.1, -0.7, -2.1, -2.1, -0.7, -0.7, 0.6, -5.7, -8.5, -11.4, -7.7, -6.3, -3.5, -2.1, -3.4, 5.4, -5.2, -8.9, -10,
 -10, 5.4, 5.4, -0.8, -3.6, -6.2, -6.8, -12.2, -17.1, -19, -18.6, -13.5, 14.8, 14.8]
y = [6.65, 4.15, 3.65, 5.05, 7.25, 8.95, 11.85, 8.95, -2, -0.6, -0.9, 1.25, 2.9, 0.9, -0.1, -1.4, 9.2, 5.2, 4.8, 6.1,
 8.9, 13.3, 17.1, 17.9, 13.8, -9.3, -5.2, -3.6, -3.6, -0.9, 3.7, 3.7, -1.8, 5.7]
```

The sensors position is at irregular intervals and spatial resolution has not been maintained here. What would be the possible approach to inject a plane wave to these sensors structure?

Comment: In 2D K-space, I think $k_x$ and $k_y$ should satisfy the relationship of $k_x^2+k_y^2=k^2$ where $k=2\pi f/c$ is the wave number. In general the solution of wave equation is given by complex exponential function $e^{j(k_xx+k_yy-\omega t)}$, so when $k_x$ or $k_y$ is greater than $k$, the other one is an imaginary number which means along that dimension the wave has an exponential decay.

Comment: Thanks. What is the primary and secondary mode of propagation? Is it seen from the plot? How to distinguish in which direction the wave propagates? Also how to find the speed of the wave?

Comment: What do you mean by mode? Does it mean discretization of $k_x$ and $k_y$? I think these modes exist in waveguides, i.e. boundary conditions are required. There is no discrete modes for a wave propagating in free field. In free field the speed of the wave is equal to $c$ which is 50 m/s in your case, while in waveguides higher order waves have different propagation speed.

Comment: Too few information about your question. Please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: From the figure, how to fix the direction of propagation of the wave along which direction? I mean where is the source and destination of the traveling wave in the K-space ?

Answer (score 3):

In your case the wave number $k = 2\pi f/c=2\pi$, $k_x$ and $k_y$ should satisfy
$$
k^2 = k_x^2+k_y^2
$$
which means they are not always real. But the direction of propagation of wave is easy to obtain given $k_x$ and $k_y$. The wave vector contains the information of both direction and the wave number:
$$
\vec{k}=k_x\vec{e}_x + k_y\vec{e}_y
$$
where $\vec{e}_x$ and $\vec{e}_y$ are unit vector along $x$ and $y$ axis, respectively.

---

Edit:

@ZaellixA already gives you a visualization of plane wave. Let me give you a animation plot to have a further look.

```
f = 10;         % frequency
fs = 100;       % sample frequency
Ts = 1/fs;      % sample period
t = 0:Ts:0.2;   % time index
c = 50;         % speed of wave
w = 2*pi*f;     % angular frequency
k = w/c;        % wave number
x = linspace(-10, 10);
y = linspace(-10, 10);
[xx, yy] = meshgrid(x, y);
theta = pi / 6; % direction of propagation
kx = k * cos(theta);
ky = k * sin(theta);

h = figure;
for n = 1:length(t)
    p = exp(-1j*(kx * xx + ky * yy - w * t(n))); % plane wave
    imagesc(x, y, real(p));
    xlabel('$x / $m', 'Interpreter', 'latex')
    ylabel('$y / $m', 'Interpreter', 'latex')
    c = colorbar;
    c.Label.String = 'Ampitude';
    caxis([-1, 1])
    drawnow

    frame = getframe(h); 
    im = frame2im(frame); 
    [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256); 
    if n == 1 
      imwrite(imind,cm,'planewave.gif','gif', 'Loopcount',inf, 'DelayTime', Ts); 
    else 
      imwrite(imind,cm,'planewave.gif','gif','WriteMode','append', 'DelayTime', Ts); 
    end 
end
```

The above MATLAB code generates an animation

[image]

Note that the axis of this figure is spatial axis $x$ and $y$, and the color axis denotes amplitude. In your picture the axis is $k_x$ and $k_y$, where every point represents a pair of $(k_x, k_y)$ **and a corresponding plane wave** with a direction of $\arctan2(k_y, k_x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. The signal travels in both directions in k-space. There are two options [-3, 0] & [0, 3]. Can I say the signal starts travel from [-3, 0]  or [0, 3]? Mathematical point of view, I understand your point, but what does physically meaning?

Comment: @Alan22 No you can't say it. The wave travels in the spatial space not k-space. $\vec{e}_x$ and $\vec{e}_y$ are unit vector in spatial space. Say a plane wave $e^{j(\omega t-\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r})}$ where $\vec{k}$ is wave vector I already defined in the answer, and $\vec{r}=x\vec{e}_x+y\vec{e}_y$ is spatial variable. This wave travels along the direction of $\vec{k}$.

Comment: So in k-space, every point represents a pair of $k_x$ and $k_y$, which yields the wave vector $\vec{k}$ and the direction of wave as well.

Comment: Probably you are right, but still I'm not fully influenced from the physical point of view (sorry for my understanding). Let a 1D signal ' d1_sig = np.sin(-(kx*X)+2.0 * np.pi *f*2)' then it gives vertical lines which represents the wave, traveling to X-direction.

Comment: @Alan22 Yes. For 2D signal, $\sin(x+y)$ gives you a plane wave in the direction of $45^\circ$, where $k_x=k_y=1$, and $k=2\pi f/c=\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}$. Does it make sense?

Comment: +1 Nice animation

Answer (score 3):

As already commented so far, for the linear wave equation to be satisfied in any number of dimensions the condition (here shown for three dimensions)

$$ k^{2} = k_{x}^{2} + k_{y}^{2} + k_{z}^{2}$$

must hold. Now, consider the complex exponential solution of the linearised wave equation of the form

$$ p(x, y, z, t) = A e^{-j \left( k_{x} x + k_{y} y + k_{z} z\right)} e^{-j \omega t}$$

The last term of above equation is the temporal term and will be skipped for the moment. The above solution represents a plane wave travelling in the direction specified by the first exponential term. To see that better consider the exponent (omitting the imaginary unit) to be of the equivalent form

$$ \mathbf{k_{x}} + \mathbf{k_{y}} + \mathbf{k_{z}} = k_{x} \mathbf{e}_{x} + k_{y} \mathbf{e}_{y} + k_{z} \mathbf{e}_{z}$$

where with bold are indicated vector values and $\mathbf{e}_{x}$, $\mathbf{e}_{y}$ and $\mathbf{e}_{z}$ represent unit vectors pointing along the specified directions. Thus, their weighted vector addition (weights being the $k$ values) forms a vector pointing towards a specific direction, albeit not a unit vector anymore. Nevertheless, the resultant vector points towards the direction of propagation of the plane wave in 3D. Of course, if any of the $k_{i}$ values is identically 0 then the propagation happens in only two dimensions, like in your case that happens in the $x-y$ plane.

Now, moving to your case specifically. In order to "create" the direction of your plane wave you have to create the components of the resultant unit vector pointing towards the direction of propagation. This is quite easy for the 2D case. In order to create a unit vector pointing towards a specific direction two specific conditions must be satisfied. First, the magnitude of the vector to be 1 and second, its angle with the $x$ axis must equal the angle of propagation. An easy choice that satisfies both conditions is

$$ \mathbf{e}_{2} = \left[ \cos \left( \theta \right), \sin \left( \theta \right) \right] $$

where the subscript denotes that this is vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. So, the resulting equation (for two dimensions this time) becomes

$$ p(x, y, t) = A e^{-j \left( k_{x} \cos \left(\theta\right) x + k_{y} \sin \left(\theta\right) y \right)} e^{-j \omega t}$$

Now the good part. Observing the above equation you may notice that on each dimension (Cartesian direction) you end up with a (co)sinusoidal component. Of course their "amplitude" is $k_{i}$. Do not be tempted to consider this to be the actual amplitude of each component, it's just a scaling factor and the final quantity ($k_{i} \cos \left( \theta \right)$, or similarly $k_{i} \sin \left( \theta \right)$), which is a **constant** for specific temporal frequency (keep in mind that $k = \frac{\omega}{c} = \frac{2 \pi f}{c}$ with $c$ being the speed of sound and $f$ the temporal frequency) and direction (this is dictated by the result of $\cos \left( \theta \right)$ or $\sin \left( \theta \right)$ which depends only on the angle of propagation $\theta$), is just a scalar that **declares the spatial frequency of the plane wave on each direction of propagation**. A simple example of this would be a plane wave traveling parallel to the $x$ axis. The expression is

$$ p(x, y, t) = A e^{-j \left( k_{x} \cos \left(\theta\right) x + k_{y} \sin \left(\theta\right) y \right)} e^{-j \omega t} \implies p(x, y, t) = A e^{-j \left( k_{x} \cos \left(0 \right) x + k_{y} \sin \left(0 \right) y \right)} e^{-j \omega t} \implies p(x, y, t) = A e^{-j k_{x} x} e^{-j \omega t} $$

Please note that we are still in two dimensions. If you get the real part you end up with the well known (co)sinusoidal solution

$$ p(x, y, t) = A \cos \left( \omega t - k_{x} x \right) $$

Below you can see an illustration of such a wave.

[image: Monochromatic plane wave with temporal frequency 100 Hz travelling parallel to the x-axis]

The picture shows a monochromatic plane wave with temporal frequency equal to $100 Hz$. Similarly, if you use a different $\theta$ and plug it in the general equation you end up with a plane wave traveling in the direction dictated by the $\theta$ parameter. An example of a monochromatic wave with the same temporal frequency and direction of travel $60^{o}$ is shown in the next image.

[image: Monochromatic plane wave with frequency 100 Hz traveling in the direction forming an angle of 60 degrees with the x-axis]

If you take a closer look, especially easy to notice on the boundaries of the screen, you may see that on each direction ($x$ and $y$ axes) there are (co)sinusoidal components forming. Those are depicted below for the plane wave of the last (second) picture (please note that the origin of the system lies in the top left corner. This is due to MATLAB's plotting function used. I apologise for the inconvenience)

[image: Spatial components of a monochromatic plane wave of temporal frequency 100 Hz traveling in a direction forming an angle with the x-axis of 60 degrees.]

Now, I believe it is quite clear that those two components constitute the spatial components of the plane wave. These are also utilised in the so called "Plane wave decomposition" methods if further simplification of the plane waves is needed. They become useful in 3D audio and array processing techniques. The frequency of the spatial components is the spatial frequency of each component governed by (actually being identical to) the respective wavenumbers ($k_{x}$ and $k_{y}$ in this case).

At this point, it is instructive to say (and easy to notice) that if you offset the constant directions by a value, the spatial component will experience a phase shift. For example, if the spatial components were not plotted for $y = 0$ and $x = 0$ but for some arbitrary $x$ and $y$ values, the corresponding spatial components would experience a phase shift. You can have a look at the respective spatial components by inspecting the 2D plot of the wave in the middle of the figure.

Although we have covered a lot of the road we haven't touched upon the temporal dimension yet. What you've seen show far is a snapshot of the monochromatic plane waves we have been talking about. Of course, if you were to take many such snapshots at different time instances you could create a "movie" of the propagating wave. The problem is that you cannot tell which way the wave is progressing towards. This is due to the fact that deal with the steady state and we cannot deduce any such information from what we have at hand. It's like floating in the middle of the ocean and moving up and down due to waves but with **absolutely no** mass transfer from the waves (this is essentially what linearised acoustic waves are). How would you be able to say which direction the waves are moving towards since you only know when you are at the peak and when you reach the lowest possible height? Well, the answer is *you can't*.

As for the velocity, it cannot be deduced from a temporal snapshot because time is "frozen". You look at the wave at a specific moment in time but in order to calculate speed you need at least two time instances to calculate the difference in position and divide by the duration ($c = \frac{x}{t}$). If you are allowed to let time change then you could possibly look for the duration between two maxima or minima (or whichever part of the cycle) and estimate the speed from that.

### Code

The code to create the plots I presented can be seen below

```
%% Set parameters
c = 343; % Speed of sound
ang = 60; % Angle of propagation
f = [100]; % Temporal frequency
Lx = 10; % length of x dimension of the domain
Ly = 10; % length of y dimension of the domain
res = 1e-2; % Resolution of the lengths

% Calculate Variables
Lx = 0:res:Lx - res; % Calculate the x-axis
Ly = Ly - res:-res:0; % Calculate the y-axis
w = 2 * pi * f; % Radial frequency
k = w/c; % Wavenumber 
kx = k .* sin(deg2rad(ang)); % x component of wavenumber
ky = k .* cos(deg2rad(ang)); % y component of wavenumber

%% Calculate signal
sig = zeros(2, length(Lx), length(Ly)); % Pre-allocate for speed

% Go through the positions (this is quite slow but is a straight forward implementation)
for xx = 1:length(Lx) % x dimension
    for yy = 1:length(Ly) % y dimension
        sig(1, xx, yy) = sin(w(1) - kx(1) * Lx(xx) - ky(1) * Ly(yy)); % Calculate the value of the plane wave on each position
    end
end

%% Visualise
figure("Name", "Plane Wave")
imagesc(squeeze(sig(1, :, :)));
xticklabels([])
yticklabels([])

figure("Name", "Components")
subplot(2, 1, 1)
temp = squeeze(sig(1, :, :));
plot(temp(1, :), 'LineWidth', 5);
grid on
xticklabels([])
yticklabels([])
title("f = " + num2str(f) + "Hz, angle = " + num2str(ang) + "^o (x component, y = 0)", 'FontSize', 24)

subplot(2, 1, 2)
plot(temp(:, 1), 'LineWidth', 5);
grid on
xticklabels([])
yticklabels([])
title("f = " + num2str(1) + "Hz, angle = " + num2str(ang) + "^o (y component, x = 0)", 'FontSize', 24)
```

Comment: P.S.: I believe you question is better suited to the Physics SE (https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

So, for 1D signal, the wave directed at 90 degree while for 2D, the direction of propagation is 45 degree.
[ N.B. unfortunately, my comment option is blocked!]

Comment: So, for 1D signal, the wave directed at 90 degree while for 2D, the direction of propagation is 45 degree. [ N.B. unfortunately, my comment option is blocked!]

Comment: For 2D, the direction of propagation is given by `atan2(ky, kx)`

Comment: @ZR Han, can you please help to interpret the next figure ( Fig. 02)?

Comment: What physical quantity does the color axis represent? If frequency $f$ is fixed to 48 Hz, then different $k$ refers to different speed. Every single $k$ is a circle in $k_x-k_y$ plane.

Comment: Color represents the cross spectral density. Also, the red blobs in the inner circle have more velocity than that of outer. Also in which direction the red blobs are moving?

Comment: $k=2\pi f/c$, the inner circle has smaller $k$ so higher $c$. The direction is given by `atan2(ky, kx)` as I already said. Draw a line from the origin to any point in the $k_x-k_y$ plane, that's the direction.

Comment: I've another question in my mind why the width of the wave ( Fig. 01, at k tends to 0 or close to center) is wider than others, though the frequency is the same for all the waves.

Comment: That is not a wave. It's kx-ky-cross spectral density plot, not x-y-amplitude.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time. From Fig. 01 & Fig. 02 represents the 2-D sine wave and 1-D sine wave plot along with the k-space meshgrid. So I think these are waves. While Fig. 03 represents spatial spectrum (derived from CSD with 2-D DFT from eq. 1 of the paper https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6382/ac348a/pdf). I want to better explain the Fig. 03. Expecting your response.

Comment: @ZaellixA, thanks for your time. Based on your analysis how do you interpret figure 03? It's a spatial pattern of the spectrum come from 2-D DFT of cross spectral densities. Also, can you share your code for the illustration of such a wave, as you showed in the plot?

Comment: I haven't encountered k-space plots before so I don't have a great intuition about them. If I have to interpret the data given to me then each point on the k-space plane should represent a plane wave of specific temporal frequency (dictated by $k^{2} = k_{x}^{2} + k_{y}^{2}$ and traveling in a specific direction given by $k_{x}$ and $k_{y}$. Now, consider the case where you keep the temporal frequency constant and you change the speed of sound. In this case you get different wavenumbers for each speed value ($k = \frac{\omega}{c}$). Thus any combination of $k_{x}$ and $k_{y}$ that (cont.)

Comment: (cont.ed) provide a specific $k$ result in constant speed. This is what most probably the circles show. Now, I am not sure exactly what use spatial cross spectrums as I haven't really used them before, so I can't be sure as to how you can use that information or any other implications may arise.

Comment: @ZaellixA, thanks for your better clarification in the above. "...traveling in a specific direction given by $k_x$ and $k_y$" I think the direction of 'red blobs' are from k-space center to the outward/periphery? Is that right [ref. Fig. 03]?

Comment: @ZRHan, good for understanding of the animation. Can you please interpret the figure 03? It's hard for me to explain the Fig. 03.

Comment: Dunno what the color axis represents for. If it has a mathematical formula, you should add it to your question. Otherwise we can do nothing to help you.

Comment: And you are reading a scientific article. The best way to understand the figure is to read the article carefully. The author should have explained the figures.

Comment: I've added the equation of spatial spectrum in the post. The color axis represents the cross spectral densities (csd). Say, $k-space$ plane is derived from $2\pi f/c$, hete $Temporal freq, f=10hz$, while I generate '$csd [f_1, f_2,.....f_n]$' I got $csd $ against a range of frequencies. Therefore, while plotting $spatial spectrum, p(k)$ in $k-space$, which frequency of $csd$ I need to consider? Can you please make  clear at that point?  I try to implement this paper https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6382/ac348a/pdf  Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Alan22 consider the $\mathbf{k}_{x}$ and $\mathbf{k}_{y}$ axes as the spatial frequencies of the components shown in the last figure of my answer. If you make the connection of those to the second figure of my answer, or the very nice animation provided by ZR Han, you'll realise that you can deduce the direction of propagation from those two as $\mathbf{k} = \sqrt{\mathbf{k}^{2}_{x} + \mathbf{k}^{2}_{y}}$ and use that in the simple plane wave exponential equation. Thus it is easy to calculate the direction of propagation for each component on the $k$-space. In addition, I believe (cont.)

Comment: it is clear that the distance from the origin shows the speed. Now, on top of that I am not sure what other information one could extract from the spatial cross-spectra. I assume that there should be some notional similarity to the temporal cross-spectra which on top of other things are also used for the calculation of the cross-correlation function. Maybe there's a way to calculate the spatial 2D cross-correlation function here to deduce spatial information from the data..... maybe not. As I've said, I have no prior experience with spatial cross-spectra.

Comment: @ZaellixA, can you suggest how to find the time continuity while appending the  wave at different time instants in the link provided https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654062/how-to-fix-temporal-discontinuity-while-generating-2d-travelling-wave-equation-i

Comment: @Alan22 I have provided a simple answer in the linked question, but as I stated there, I believe your problem is not in coding your solution but on the use of the available dimensionality to represent your solution. The latter is absolutely correct as far as I can tell but you have to use an additional dimension to represent the temporal evolution of your solution.

Comment: @ZaellixA, I've updated the question above. Can you help me to inject the plane wave in the X & Y position of sensors, given above? The sensor's position is fixed.

Comment: @ZRHan, I've edited the question above. Can you please have a look at that?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean with "inject the plane wave in the X & Y position of sensors". I assume you would like to get the temporal evolution of the plane wave at some specific points. So, all you have to do is find the coordinates of the sensors and use those for the $x$ and $y$ coordinates (instead of creating a matrix for the whole domain) and plug them into your equations. What you'll get is an equation dependent only on time (as the spatial coordinates will become constants). If this is not what you need or want a more detailed explanation please let us know.

Comment: Additionally, I suggest you post a new question to address this problem. This will allow more people to see you issue and help and provide a reference point for related questions or allow people with the same or similar problems to find a solution.

Comment: @ZaellixA probably, you are right but can you please show this in matlab/python plotting  to make the situation understandable. I think when I have spatial coordinates (x,y) of the sensors, then the time is fixed, isn't it?

Comment: @ZaellixA, created new post in the link https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82349/how-to-inject-a-2d-plane-sine-wave-to-the-array-of-seismic-sensors. please check.

Comment: @ZRHan, Can you please have a look at the figure and comment on it ? Sorry, the script is in Python. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82903/what-is-going-wrong-with-the-plot-of-2d-spatial-spectrum-at-a-specific-frequency

Answer (score 0):

I can change the above python script to plot the 2 dimensional plane wave. The script is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cmath
from scipy import signal
import math

f = 19;         # Temporal frequency
fs = 100;       # sampling frequency
Ts = 1/fs;      # sample period
t = np.arange(0, 25, Ts);   # time index
c = 40;         # speed of wave
w = 2*np.pi *f;     # angular frequency
k = 2.0 * np.pi * f / c  # wavenumber

#*** Here Nyquist sampling frequency w.r.t. space #####
resolution = 0.01   # Spatial resolution
x = np.arange(-1.5, 1.5, resolution)
y = np.arange(-1.5, 1.5, resolution)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y) 

psi = np.pi / 6 #% direction of propagation
kx = k * np.cos(psi)
ky = k * np.sin(psi)
t= np.arange(0, 10, 1)

#2D sine wave 
d2_sig = np.sin(-(kx*X+ky*Y)+w*t[5]) 


plt.figure()
c = plt.imshow(d2_sig, cmap='seismic', vmin=d2_sig.min(), vmax=d2_sig.max(), extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()],
               interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')
plt.colorbar(c)
plt.xlabel("Distance, $X$ [Meter]", fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel("Distance,$Y$ [Meter]", fontsize=18)
plt.title(f'Progressive wave', weight="bold")
```

[image: Travelling Wave]

N.B. The above python script has been presented with the help of the above matlab scripts provided by ZaellixA & ZR Han.

Comment: Your code is correct. It is very similar to what both answers (mine and ZR Han's) have presented. If you would like to add more information to the question, please edit it and don't post it as an answer. Otherwise, if this is the exact answer you have been looking for, mark it appropriately.

Comment: @ZaellixA, can you please have a look at the link https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82903/what-is-going-wrong-with-the-plot-of-2d-spatial-spectrum-at-a-specific-frequency. Sorry, the script is in Python.